# How to get path in NetRW?

Tags: netrw

I want to override NetRW's response to `<CR>`.  When I hit enter, I want to:

- get the path of the file or directory of the line with the cursor in the `:Lex` window
- test if path is a file
- if the path is a file:

  - the explorer from `:Lex` closes
  - `tab drop` to the path
  - open `:Lex`

However, I have no idea how I can get the path or directory of the line with the cursor in the `:Lex` window, without opening the file first.  Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found a better way without opening file, and is consistent.

```
netrw#Call('NetrwFile', netrw#Call('NetrwGetWord'))
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a couple ideas:

- Combine `b:netrw_curdir` with `expand('<cfile>')` to get the path, then do you want you want. There's some trickiness with getting the file on the line at the cursor because `netrw` has various possible "formats."
- Run the original to open the file (`:execute "normal \<Plug>NetrwLocalBrowseCheck"`), grab the path (`expand('%')`), `:Rexplore` to go back to the previous state, then do what you want.

---

I found the `<Plug>` mapping by opening netrw and checking `:map <CR>`.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the source code of netrw, I finnaly find the way.

```
let l:pathUnderCursor=netrw#Call('NetrwTreePath', w:netrw_treetop)
```

The `l:pathUnderCursor` will get the absolute path under the cursor of the netrw line.The function `NetrwTreePath` is an internal function in the script `netrw.vim`, to call it you need to use a form like this `netrw#Call`.
And here is the source code [netrw.vim](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/autoload/netrw.vim):